Simplifying $10^{2380849\cdot 10^{10^{120.20}}-1}$ using Knuth's Up-Arrow notation
Is there a good way to simplify the monstrous number $10^{2380849\cdot 10^{10^{120.20}}-1}$ using Knuth's Up-Arrow notation? I have tried to research how this could be done, but the notation still confuses me. I'm not expecting the Up-Arrow notation to give a number in return that is exactly the same as $10^{2380849\cdot 10^{10^{120.20}}-1}$, but something that is in the same ballpark would be great.
I appreciate your answer.

This number is not large enough for up-arrow notation to be of much use. It's "essentially" the same as $10^{10^{10^{10^{2.08}}}}$ (the factor of $2380849$ in the first level exponent is utterly irrelevant), so it's between $10 \uparrow \uparrow 4$ and $10 \uparrow \uparrow 5.$
If you want a good approximation of the form $m \uparrow \uparrow n$ where $m$ and $n$ are $1$-digit integers (or perhaps for more accuracy, try using $2$-digit integers for $m),$ then "trial and error" is probably quickest. For example, $2 \uparrow \uparrow 6$ is $10^{10^{10^{4.295 \ldots}}}$ and $2 \uparrow \uparrow 7$ is $10^{10^{10^{10^{4.295 \ldots}}}}$, so your number is between $2 \uparrow \uparrow 6$ and $2 \uparrow \uparrow 7,$ with $2 \uparrow \uparrow 7$ probably being a better fit.
The following sci.math posts I made 22 years ago might be of interest.
GRAHAM'S NUMBER AND RAPIDLY GROWING FUNCTIONS [2 March 2002]
http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/0f3c8bab92145996
BIG NUMBERS #1 [8 April 2002]
http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/403051f310ff3dfc
BIG NUMBERS #2 [8 April 2002]
http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/d12962e3af2c74b7
BIG NUMBERS #3 [8 April 2002]
http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/4f2ed8e0385b72f2
